# What is 'Looped' railing?

Tags: meaning-in-context

This is the only description about it.

> **Looped** railing : These **loops** are as beautiful as they are solid.

What is 'Looped' railing mean?

Comment: Source of the quote, please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Railing" is a metal (iron) fence made of metal rods (not sheets).

Looped railing would appear to mean that the metal rods are bent into loops at the top. This is also called "bow top railing"

[image]

From "[York Gates](https://www.yorkgates.co.uk/yorkgatesshop/prod_3829562-Bow-Top-railings.html)"